# Choosing Groups And Deleting Some

Tags: combinatorics

There will be 8 women and 6 men, we shell build a board including 3 women and 3 men, but there are 2 men that refuse to be on the board together.

What I have thought that there are 2 options:
1. not to take the 2 that refuse to seat together that is $4\choose3$ 
2. to choose just one of them each time twice $5\choose3$ but then I get to the sum of 24 when it is 20 when there are no limitations ($6\choose3$).

The answer is 896, is there an option I need to take the case with no limitations and reduce the case none of them is chosen? that make no sense

Comment: Choosing a group of $3$ men including exactly one of our unpleasant people can be done in $(2)\binom{4}{2}$ ways. Add to your previous $\binom{4}{3}$. Or else from the  $\binom{6}{3}$ no restriction ways, subtract the $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to have these two men plus one other.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why is it (2)*$4\choose2$?

Comment: We can choose either of the bad guys. That's the $2$. Then we need to choose $2$ other men from the $4$ good guys to join the bad guy on the committee.

Comment: @AndréNicolas sorry I do not get it, we need to create a group of 3 men from 6, why we always use 4?

Comment: Suppose that the bad guys are Albert and Bob. To choose $3$ men for the commitee, among them Albert, we must choose Albert and **two** other, neither of them Bob. There are altogether $6$ men, so there are $4$ who are neither Albert nor Bob. We choose $2$ from these.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I got it! so when choosing Albert or Bob because we choose 2 good guys from the 6 we have 4 left?
How do you know that $4\choose 1$ are the way to choose both Albert or Bob?

Comment: I wrote an answer. If you make a group of $3$ men that includes both Albert and Bob, you have $1$ empty slot to fill, from the $4$ other men. The number of ways to do this is $\binom{4}{1}$, or more simply just plain $4$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas empty slot? you mean that we have sets of 3s that one need to be erase?

Answer (score 2):

Call men refusing $A$ and $B$, there are $3$ cases:

1) There are nor $A$ neither $B$: $$\binom{8}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{3}$$

2) There is $A$ but there isn't $B$: $$\binom{8}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{2}$$

3) There is $B$ but there isn't $A$: $$\binom{8}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{2}$$

So the answer is $$\binom{8}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{3} + 2 \cdot \binom{8}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{2} $$

Comment: Instead of $5\choose{2}$, you want $4\choose{2}$.  For example, you pick A, skip B, then pick $2$ of the remaining $4$.

Comment: @user3294068: I edited

Comment: but why is it $4\choose2$? if it is 4 so you removed 2 men

Comment: @gbox:because if , for example , there is $A$ but not $B$, we can't choose $B$ and $A$ is already chosen, so we can choose among $6-4$ men

Answer (score 1):

Call a group of $3$ men **bad** if it includes both of our quarrelsome men.

There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ men without restriction. How many groups of $3$ men are bad? A bad group must have our two quarrelsome men on it, together with $1$ man chosen from the other $4$. So there are $\binom{4}{1}$ bad groups of $3$ men.

It follows there are $\binom{6}{3}-\binom{4}{1}$ good groups of $3$ men. The women are more reasonable, and there are $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ of them. Thus the number of committees is 
$\binom{8}{3}\left[\binom{6}{3}-\binom{4}{1}\right]$.